# Best practices with entity inheritance in Controllers

Tags: symfony

How do you call constructors and forms in a controller to avoid to duplicate code in inheritance context ?

For instance :

**Entities:**

```
class Shape {
…
}

class Circle extends Shape {
…
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
…
}
```

**Controller:**

I need to manage many and many subclasses like Circle, Rectangle, Rhombus, Square… and I want to have just one controller. So for the CRUD actions ?

For now, It's like this :

```
class ShapeController extends Controller {

/**
 * @Route("/shape/index", name="shape_index")
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $shapes = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Shape')->findAll();
    return $this->render('shape/index.html.twig', [
        'shapes' => $shapes
    ]);
}


/**
 * @Route("/shape/{type}/new", name="shape_new")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request, $type)
{
    $formtype = 'AppBundle\Entity\\'.ucfirst($type).'Type';
    $class = 'AppBundle\Entity\\'.ucfirst($type);
    $shape = new $class();
    $form = $this->createForm(new $formtype(), $shape);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($shape);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
            'shape_index'
        ));
    }

    return $this->render('shape/new.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'shape' => $shape
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It better to use factories. A `ShapeFactory->createFromType($type)` and a `ShapeTypeFactory->createFromType($type)`.

Then you will only need to use those factories in your controller, and let the responsability of wich Shape/ShapeType instance you need to the factories.

Comment: And those factories are used as services ?

Comment: yes you need to register them in your `services.yml` file. then use them in the controller with `$this->get('service_name')`

Comment: Ok, i'm okay with that, but in my case, how I pass the parameter "type" ?

Comment: you pass `$type` to the factory function of the desired factory service in the controller. Suppose you have a `app.factory.shape_entity` service (instance of a ShapeFactory), then in your controller just call `$shape = $this->get('app.factory.shape_entity')->createFromType($type);`